# Django: too many values to unpack (expected 2) while making dynamic Q OR model query

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, model

I am currently trying to dynamically generate a Django or query using Q objects. I have created some code to do so based off of what I've read people having success with, however I'm not having any with my implementation. My code is as follows

```
query = reduce(or_, (Q(target[search_class] + '__icontains=' + keyword) for search_class in range(2, len(target))))

model.objects.filter(query) # Error happens while making the query itself (too many values to unpack (expected 2))
```

This is the simplest implementation of this method that I could find. Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try, model.objects.filter(**query)

Comment: @SarojRai yes, I tired that and the error when I did that was: filter() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having a similar problem, after tons of tinkering, I was able to fix this issue using the following code:

```
matching = []
matching.extend(model.filter(reduce(or_, (Q(**{target[search_class] + '__icontains': keyword}) for search_class in range(3, len(target))))))
```